# Same URL iFrames but using different session data

Tags: php, session, iframe

I have 2x iframes that includes the same website (from same origin).

I'm using sessions to switch between 2x different database tables, depending on which iframe they use. One is for Employees, the other is for Customers. I do this by differentiating with a URL parameter

```
<iframe src="website/index.php?customer=1" frameborder="0" style="width:100%; height:100%;" name="product_frame" id="product_frame"></iframe>
```

It then registers which iframe is being used and in turn uses the correct DB table in my queries.

This works fine unless the user goes to the other iframe and navigates, it detects the URL parameter isn't there and rewrites the session information, so if you go back to the other iframe, the incorrect data is shown.

How can I know that the user is in a specific iframe even if they switch between both?

I know one solution would be to have 2x completely different directories and clone the website but this seems excessive.

Comment: Why do you need the Session for this? Can't you just read from the URL parameter every time?

Comment: In fact, why do you need iframes for this at all? Why not have a single page which provides all the necessary functionality?

Comment: The URL parameter in the iframe only carrys on the first page, not subsequent pages when the site is navigated, so I set it in the session so it's saved.

Comment: Well you could change it so it passes the parameter around. But really I can't see why there's a need for frames at all, especially if it's all pages from the same site. Sounds like a bit of 1990s design

Comment: If it were not in an iframe, the issue would still apply? Because the site is in the same directory, it would still get confused if you were to navigate between the 2.

Comment: You would surely have all the functionality in a single page? Maybe with ajax to help. Then you'd get a similar effect to what you have currently, but with a modern user experience  and no session issues